# Using top level item in nested subquery with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have a query when I'm attempting to find a link between two tables, but I require few checks with association tables within the same query. I think my problem stems from having to check across multiple levels of relationships, where I want to filter a subquery based on the top level item, but I've hit an issue and have no idea how to proceed.

More specifically I want to query `Script` using the name of an `Application`, but narrow the results down to when the `Application`'s `Language` matches the `Script`'s `Language`.

**Tables:** `Script (id, language_id)`, `Application (id, name)`, `Language (id)`

**Association Tables:** `ApplicationLanguage (app_id, language_id)`, `ScriptApplication (script_id, app_id)`

**Current attempt:** (it's important this stays as a single query)

```
value = 'appname'

# Search applications for a value
app_search = select([Application.id]).where(Application.name==value).as_scalar()

# Search for applications matching the language of the script
lang_search = select([ApplicationLanguage.app_id]).where(
    ApplicationLanguage.language_id==Script.language_id
).as_scalar()

# Find the script based on which applications appear in both subqueries.
script_search = select([ScriptApplication.script_id]).where(and_(
    ScriptApplication.app_id.in_(app_search),
    ScriptApplication.app_id.in_(lang_search),
)).as_scalar()

# Turn it into an SQL expression
query = Script.id.in_(script_search)
```

**Resulting SQL code:**

```
SELECT script.id AS script_id
FROM script
WHERE script.id IN (SELECT script_application.script_id
FROM script_application
WHERE script_application.application_id IN (SELECT application.id
FROM application
WHERE application.name = ?) AND script_application.application_id IN (SELECT application_language.application_id
FROM application_language, script
WHERE script.language_id = application_language.language_id))
```

**My theory**

I believe the issue is on the line `ApplicationLanguage.language_id==Script.language_id`, because if I change it to (`ApplicationLanguage.language_id==3`, 3 being the value I'm expecting), then it works perfectly. In the SQL code, I assume it's the `FROM application_language, script` which is overwriting the top level `script`

How would I go about either rearranging or fixing this query? My current method seems to work fine if it's across a single relationship, just doesn't work if I try and do anything more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I'd still love to know how I'd go about fixing the original query as I believe it'll come in useful in the future, but I managed to rearrange it.

I reversed the `lang_search` to grab languages for each application from `app_search`, and used that as part of the final query, instead of attempting to combine it in a subquery.

```
value = 'appname'

app_search = select([Application.id]).where(Application.name==value).as_scalar()

lang_search = select([ApplicationLanguage.language_id]).where(
    ApplicationLanguage.app_id.in(app_search)
).as_scalar()

script_search = select([ScriptApplication.script_id]).where(and_(
    ScriptApplication.app_id.in(app_search),
)).as_scalar()

query = and_(
    Script.id.in_(script_search),
    Script.language_id.in_(lang_search),
)
```

Final SQL query:

```
SELECT script.id AS script_id
FROM script
WHERE script.id IN (SELECT script_application.script_id
FROM script_application
WHERE script_application.application_id IN (SELECT application.id
FROM application
WHERE lower(application.name) = ?)) AND script.language_id IN (SELECT application_language.language_id
FROM application_language
WHERE application_language.application_id IN (SELECT application.id
FROM application
WHERE lower(application.name) = ?))
```